# How do I install on an encrypted disk now that there is no alternate CD?

Tags: installation, encryption

How do I install Raring in an encrypted disk?

There's no alternate CD and on regular raring CD there is no option to mount the existing encrypted partitions!

Answer (score 1):

I've just done it with the old command line installer mini CD at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

In searching for a fix, I notice a bunch of bugs in encrypted installs. Maybe they disabled it rather than take chances. But, they should have mentioned it in the release notes.

BTW, I also tried creating the LVM crypt disk setup before starting the installer. It did see it, but when I tried to boot, I just got the intrmfs prompt. So don't waste your time on it.